# How to load a TSV containing a JSON field in Pig Latin?

Tags: json, apache-pig, csv

I am trying to load a file with a schema that is primarily TSV (tab separated values), but one of the fields is a JSON value. It seems that pig latin has TextLoader for tab (or other) separated values, and JsonLoader for JSON...

In particular, the each row of data looks like:

```
date\tevent_name\tevent_details\n
```

where event_details is a JSON formatted string. The others are simply char arrays.

What is the easiest way to load this data?

Notes: i'm using Pig ver 0.11.1.

Answer (score 10):

(After doing a bunch of research, here is the answer:)

Download the necessary libraries from http://mvnrepository.com/ needed for the register commands.

The pig script would be as follows:

```
register 'libs/elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar';
register 'libs/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';
register 'libs/guava-14.0.1.jar';
register 'libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar';
register 'libs/piggybank.jar';

define decode_json com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.piggybank.JsonStringToMap();

e1 = load '$filename' using PigStorage() as (
    date: chararray,
    event_name: chararray,
    event_details_str: chararray,
);

-- Remove the header row:
e2 = filter e1 by not date matches '.*DATE';

-- Convert the event_details from a JSON string to a map:
events = foreach e2 generate *, decode_json(event_details_str) as event_details;
```

Answer (score 3):

mbells answer works fine, one thing I was struggling with was how to retrieve the map values.
Below is an example of retrieving key1, key2 from events map.

```
fields = FOREACH events GENERATE events#'key1', events#'key2';
```